# How to test for type using a Type variable?

Tags: dart

Is it possible to test the type of an object in Dart using an instance of Type stored in a variable? e.g.

```
Foo foo = new Foo();

Type testtype = Foo;

if (foo is testtype) {
  print("foo matched testype");
}
```

This gives me the following warning:

```
The name 'testtype' is not a type and cannot be used in an 'is' expression
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Ultimately I want to pass the Type into a function as a parameter which then performs the "is" type test using this.

Comment: If this issue is fixed with a method in Type, it may solve your problem: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=13856. On the other hand, your code gives a warning but it works (maybe try filing a bug for the warning).

Comment: Strangely I no longer get the warning. However, the "is" test now always succeeds. I can set testtype to anything and the message is always printed.

Answer (score 1):

```dart
Foo foo = new Foo();

Type testtype = Foo;

if (foo.runtimeType == testtype) {
  print("foo matched testype");
}
```

Comment: Ditto comment to financeCoding

Answer (score 0):

If (foo.runtimeType == testtype.runtimeType)

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this method. However, I want the test to include subtypes which I believe the "is" test does.